# mysql left join but need value from third table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I've read a hundred different "how to join three tables" posts, but can't seem to get mine to do what I want.  It seems different than the examples I've found online, which are simply two left joins.

```
tests
-----
id
name
platformA <<-- boolean, platformA supports test?
platformB
platformX

testgroups  <<-- tuple (testid,platid) is unique
----------
testid      <<-- matches 'id' in 'tests' table above
platid      <<-- matches id in 'platforms' table below
grouptype

platforms
---------
id
name <<-- corresponds to column name 'platform?' in 'tests'
```

OK, so I know I want to left join testgroups to tests, because I want a result that has exactly one row for each test name in 'tests' where platformA is 1, regardless of whether there is such an entry in testgroups.  What I can't figure out is how to get the platforms table involved.  Here is what I have that does NOT work:

```
select tests.name, testgroups.grouptype from tests
left join testgroups on (tests.id = testgroups.testid)
where tests.platformA = 1;
```

This does not work because of the fact that testgroups can have multiple testid = 2, one for each platid = ??.  The tuple is guaranteed to be unique, but not either of the columns by itself.  So, it gives me, for each tests.name, a row for each platform.  I need to limit it by the platform name (say, platformA), which I know, but to which I do not have access in table testgroups.  So, if I knew the platid instead of the platform name, I could do this, which does work:

```
select tests.name, testgroups.grouptype from tests
left join testgroups on (tests.id = testgroups.testid and testgroups.platid = 27)
where tests.platformA = 1;
```

I know I want only platformA, but I don't know its id is (in example above) 27 without looking it up in the platforms table.  How do I incorporate this into my query?  I've tried a lot of combinations, none of which work quite right.  Here is one example of what I thought might work:

```
select tests.name, testgroups.grouptype from tests, platforms
left join testgroups on (tests.id = testgroups.testid and platforms.name = 'platformA')
where tests.platformA = 1;
```

This seems to be illegal syntax.  I've also tried multiple left joins, which does not work for me.

I'd love the answer, but would also love a bit of explanation about why it works, since I have been banging my head for a while now.

Thanks,
David

==== update ====

I think @Marc is almost right, but it limits my output by the rows where testgroups.platid has data for that platform.

Here is my attempt at using his answer and giving my complete query:

```
select tests.name, testgroups.grouptype from tests
left join testgroups on (tests.id = testgroups.testid)
left join platforms on (testgroups.platid = platforms.id)
where tests.platformA = 1 and (platforms.name = 'platformA' or platforms.id is null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple joins in a single query, exactly as in your last sample... except you should NOT mix join styles.

```
select tests.name, testgroups.grouptype
from tests
left join testgroups on tests.id = testgroups.testid
left join platforms ON ......
where tests.platformA = 1 and platforms.name = 'platformA';
```

Comment: Well, I'll give Marc B the correct answer, although you should read my update, since it is the more correct answer.